# It it possible to soften hard soil without removing a lawn?

Tags: lawn, soil, lawn-repair

My lawn was done some 2 years ago but I had many problems: it wasn't level, and in some spots it was very hard (probably due to compaction and clayish soil). The people who did it told be it would even out and soften within a few months, but nothing like that happened.

Is it possible to salvage it without tearing it down and redoing??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can run a core aerator over it (or do it manually with a hand aerator depending on size)  - you want one that cuts out small plugs, not one that cuts slits. Once you have pulled up a bunch of cores and let them dry on the surface, you can rake those around a bit and fill in some low spots, but for serious lumps you may need to bring in material to get towards level. If you do that gradually, the grass will continue to grow, where if you try to get it all in one go some will be so deeply buried you'll have to re-seed.

Adding 1/4" of compost will help with both health and texture.

While you are describing lumps rather than depressions, my answer here should still apply for the gradual solution approach: [How should I fill and reseed shallow depressions in my lawn?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17992/how-should-i-fill-and-reseed-shallow-depressions-in-my-lawn?rq=1)

Comment: I tried to find a core aerator already, but in Brazil that is unknown, so I tried to make one myself welding some pipes, and it sort of work but got clogged up really fast and wasn't really taking the cores out. Should the soil b damp for that??

Comment: The tubes should be open on top, sharpened on the bottom exterior - cores should push out (so the first time, nothing comes out - the second time, the first core comes out, the third time the second core comes out, etc - before storing the tool, clean the last core out with a stick/rod. Slightly damp soil will help.