# Best method for filling depressed areas in grass?

Tags: grass

I had a drainage system installed in my lawn, which required burying some pipes in trenches cut into the lawn.  After several weeks, the dirt used to fill those trenches has compacted, leaving a big dip in the lawn (in places, 3 to 4 inches deep), running the length of where the trenches were.

What's the best way to fill those depressed areas with minimal damage to the grass growing there?  Should I slowly add dirt to the top of the grass, letting it fill in over time? Or should I dig up the grass (possibly damaging its roots) and add dirt underneath it?

Comment: You can do either. I prefer the fill in approach as it's less fuss, but if you want to cut sod and level it, go to. Details given here: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/17996/6806

Comment: If you live in an area where the ground freezes during the winter, then the depressed areas are likely to get deeper when the ground thaws in the spring. I've seen dips up to one foot deep in my city the spring after some water mains were replaced.

Comment: @Jurp oh, that's great info.  I do live in an area where it freezes and it causes a lot of ground shifting.  I'll probably wait until Spring to make any changes then.